# Prove a variation of integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

*I stuck on this problem for a very long time and I felt that I may not know the context behind the problem.

In the first step, we are required to find $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(\zeta)\bar z}{R^2-\zeta \bar z} d\zeta $ for z inside D(0;R). This is simple since the function does not have any poles in D, so the answer is simply 0.

Next we are required to show $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(\zeta)(R^2-|z|^2)}{(\zeta -z) (R^2-\zeta \bar z)} d\zeta $, and confusion hits me. I know the condition in the first step should be used, and maybe a little mimick on the proof for Cauchy Integral Formula? But all my attempts to decompose it seems of no use.

*Thanks for the hint of the accepted answer. Here I present my proposed solution:

1. $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(\zeta)(R^2-|z|^2)}{(\zeta -z) (R^2-\zeta \bar z)} d\zeta = \frac{(R^2-|z|^2)}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta -z) (R^2-\zeta \bar z)} d\zeta $,
2. (Apply Rational Function Decomposition) $\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta -z) (R^2-\zeta \bar z)} $= $\frac{A}{(\zeta -z)} +\frac{B}{(R^2-\zeta \bar z)} $, we can leave the latter part behind, since it has no poles.  Multiply $(\zeta - z)$ to each side, and we have A = $\frac{f(z)}{R^2-z^2}$, and apply Cauchy Integral Formula, we get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with pull out $R^{2}-|z|^{2}$ since this is independent of $\zeta$. Next note that $g(\zeta)=\frac {f(\zeta)} {R^{2}-\zeta \overline z}$ is analytic and you can apply Cauchy's Integral Formula to it. You will end up with $(R^{2}-|z|^{2}) \frac {f(z)} {R^{2}-|z|^{2}}=f(z)$.

Comment: Can you explain more on how to apply Cauchy's Integral Formula to it? It is not similar to what I have learnt.

Comment: There was  a mistake. I have edited  the answer. I hope it is clear now.